# How to connect a Fingerprint reader digitalpersona 4500 with angular?

Tags: angular, fingerprint, digital-persona-sdk

I'm doing an assitance program for my employes, and I want to connect that fingerprint with angular but I don't know how can I connect and if it is possible, because I don't find good information in the web... any idea? or is better use a programming language?